# How do I list all registered implementation in ninject

Tags: c#, ninject

I am using ninject and have an interface `IService` which has multiple implementations.

Now I have a class (which is also constructed via ninject) where I am interested in the Assemblies for every implementation (I want to access the embedded resoures)

Currently I am doing this

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(IEnumerable<IService> services)
    {
        this.assemblies = services
            .Select(m => m.GetType().Assembly)
            .GroupBy(g => g.FullName)
            .Select(x => x.First())
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

which does the trick but is awfull because I am already constructing every service instance one just to trow it away. I don't even need any service at this point.

I already tried to inject an IKernel to my class instead and call `kernel.GetBindings(typeof(IService))` but I can't figure out how to determine the type.

I know that a binding could be a method or a constant but I can filter by `Target = BindingTarget.Type`